# How to reference ranges rather than separate numbers?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I would like to do the following:

Just type something like

```
... we describe this in sections \mycoolref{winter,spring,summer,fall} ...
```

and it will be typeset as something like

> ... we describe this in sections 2.1 to 2.4.

One might say that I could just type

```
... we describe this in sections \ref{winter} to \ref{fall} ...
```

But the tricky thing is that I might decide to change the order of my `winter`, `spring`, `summer`, `fall` sections later, and I don't want to have to change my references because of this.

One could imagine a fancy command that takes a set of labels and generates a compact description that consists of ranges if possible, like

> 2.1, 2.3 to 2.8, and 2.12

Or, does such a macro exist?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The [`cleveref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package sorts and compresses cross-references. It also automatically determines the format of references, so that you don't have to type "section" in the source.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\section{winter}\label{winter}

\section{spring}\label{spring}

\section{summer}\label{summer}

\section{fall}\label{fall}

\section{christmas}\label{christmas}

\section{easter}\label{easter}

\section{pentecost}\label{pentecost}

We describe this in \cref{winter,fall,christmas,summer,pentecost} \dots

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, cleveref doesn’t hyperlink the text properly. It merely links the number(s), not the leading text. Which is understandable when there’s multiple references, but very annoying when there’s only a single reference (“see section X” will only make the “X” a link, not the whole “section X”).

Comment: @Konrad: Use `\crefformat{section}{#2section~#1#3}` to get what you want. Read the cleveref manual for details.

Comment: @Lev: I feel stupid now. Thanks. *However*, is there a way to adapt this format for all label types without the need redefine them all explicitly? I’m currently using `\@for` to solve this (and it works) but it’s clunky and has to be maintained manually whenever a new float type is added.

Comment: @Konrad: Ask a separate question?

Comment: @Caramdir: I already have … http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6428/42

Comment: @AhmedMusa: Load `cleveref` *after* `hyperref`.

Comment: @lockstep: Thanks. I can't find it in the *cleveref* documentation: does *cleveref* have an option for loading *hyperref* on its own? This will relieve the user of the order of loading.

Comment: @AhmedMusa: I don't think there's such an option.

Comment: @KonradRudolph As you probably know by now, `cleveref` has the `nameinlink` option that puts the reference name into the hyperlink.