# Compressing ranges of labels of different types?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref, amsthm

How to compress a range of references of different types?

Let us assume the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\crefname{lem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\Crefname{lem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\crefname{thm}{Thm.}{Thms.}
\Crefname{thm}{Thm.}{Thms.}
\crefname{cor}{Cor.}{Cors.}
\Crefname{cor}{Cor.}{Cors.}
\crefname{prop}{Prop.}{Props.}
\Crefname{prop}{Prop.}{Props.}
\begin{document}
\begin{thm}\label{A}A\end{thm}
\begin{lem}\label{B}B\end{lem}
\begin{cor}\label{C}C\end{cor}
\begin{lem}\label{D}D\end{lem}
\begin{prop}\label{E}E\end{prop}
We expect ``Thm.\@ 0.1, Lemma 0.2, Cor.\@ 0.3, and Prop.\@ 0.5'' here: \cref{A,B,C,E}.

We expect ``0.1 to 0.3 and 0.5'' here: \myawesomeref{A,B,C,E}.
\end{document}
```

Is there a command (denoted above as `\myawesomeref`) within `cleveref` or another package giving us that automation? I am likely to move the claims throughout the document while writing, so I would not like to hardcode numbers or ranges.

So far I have tried `\labelcref` with aliases (see the [original answer by hooy](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/369687/30280)), but this combination would change the output of `\cref`, which we actually want to retain.

Yes, I've looked at [How to reference ranges rather than separate numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7624/how-to-reference-ranges-rather-than-separate-numbers) .

Comment: Your request makes some sense for theorem-like environments if the different environments share a counter (so have unique labels). But it doesn't make sense in general. If \myawesomeref compressed references to different types, how will readers know if "1, 2 and 4" refer to sec. 1, eq. 2 and thm. 4, or to eq. 1, thm. 2 and eq. 4? \myawesomeref{sec1,eq2,thm4} and `\myawesomeref{eq1,thm2,eq4} would produce identical output. Cleveref contains general-purpose commands that must cope with any reference types. That's why \labelcref complains if you pass it references of more than one type.

Comment: Sure, that's what I meant by "Your request makes some sense for theorem-like environments if the different environments share a counter (so have unique labels)." Why comment doesn't solve your problem, which is why I only posted it as a comment. I was just attempting to explain why the cleveref package doesn't currently provide this feature. \labelcref has to work sensibly for any reference type, and in general it can't unambiguously typeset references of different types.

Comment: I know. I'm explaining *why* \labelcref can't be expected to do what you want, and why I can't/won't modify it in the cleveref package to do the job you want. (Because it would generate nonsense cross-references in many cases.)

Comment: It wouldn't be too difficult to define a new command based on the \labelcref code that ignores the reference type when sorting and compressing. I'm not sure whether such a command belongs in the cleveref package, though. It would work fine for your specific use-case, but would produce nonsense cross-references for many other cases. It would be necessary to check and warn/error when the cross-reference is nonsense (see my above examples). But this is much more work, and not so easy.

Answer (score 5):

You can indeed use `cleveref`. You have to declare the lemmas and the other environments as aliases to theorems using `\crefalias{lem}{thm}` combined with `\labelcref{...}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}

\crefname{lem}{lemma}{lemmas}
\Crefname{lem}{Lemma}{Lemmas}
\crefname{thm}{theorem}{theorems}
\Crefname{thm}{Theorem}{Theorems}

\crefalias{lem}{thm}

\begin{document}

\begin{thm}\label{A}
A
\end{thm}

\begin{lem}\label{B}
B
\end{lem}

\begin{thm}\label{C}
C
\end{thm}

\begin{lem}\label{D}
D
\end{lem}

See claims \labelcref{A,B,D}.

\end{document}
```

> [image: Output]

Comment: @LeonMeier That was not part of the question. If that is needed, such information must be included in the question, or else I'd have to bring my crystal ball out of storage.

Comment: That's fair, and technically they do, as they still produce the output one would expect. What you didn't specify in your original question was that you also wanted the names for "lemma" and "theorem" etc. to still be distinct. The only thing you said was that you didn't want them displayed in the requested output, which would make it irrelevant whether they were identical or not. Now that you have mentioned that you still want them to keep the distinct names, the solution will of course be different.

Comment: To whoever downvoted; why?