# How to make a range reference use an en-dash?

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

I just read:

[How to reference ranges rather than separate numbers?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7624/how-to-reference-ranges-rather-than-separate-numbers)

but the accepted answer doesn't do quite what I want: I'd like to get `sections 1--4`, not `sections 1 to 4`. The latter is perfectly fine, it's just not my preference. Can I do this?

An example in case it helps:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\section{The first  section}\label{sec:first}
\section{The second section}\label{sec:second}
\section{The third  section}\label{sec:third}
\section{The fourth section}\label{sec:fourth}
\section{The fifth  section}\label{sec:fifth}

The reference: \cref{sec:first,sec:second,sec:third,sec:fourth,sec:fifth}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The first step is to make a complete example.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: I actually don't think that matters, but, sure, there you go.

Comment: Nitpicking, but you are asking how to make a range use an _en-dash_, not a hyphen.

Comment: Hm. You think my time doesn't matter? Well then I think your question doesn't matter either.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: No, I just didn't think that the concrete example would help answer my question, since it's general and not specific. (Plus I linked to the other question which also did not have a complet example and that did not prevent it from being answered and upvoted. Plus one of the answers to the linked-to question has a complete example.) - but when you asked for an example, I provided it.

Comment: @Guildenstern: Indeed.

Comment: `\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}`? It's documented in the `cleveref`documentation

Comment: @UlrikeFischer: ... and my first comment was certainly not intended to disrespect your investment of time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This specific use is documented in the `cleveref` documentation. Use

```
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}
```

where `\crefrangeconjunction` controls the formatting of the conjunction in cleveref range references.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\newcommand{\crefrangeconjunction}{--}

\begin{document}
    \section{The first  section}\label{sec:first}
    \section{The second section}\label{sec:second}
    \section{The third  section}\label{sec:third}
    \section{The fourth section}\label{sec:fourth}
    \section{The fifth  section}\label{sec:fifth}

    The reference: \cref{sec:first,sec:second,sec:third,sec:fourth,sec:fifth}
\end{document}
```

[image: cref]

Comment: I somehow missed that and only noticed `\crefrangeformat`.

Answer (score 0):

To make that happen for a specific reference type (say, section), we can use:

```
\crefrangeformat{section}{sections~(#3#1#4)--(#5#2#6)}
```

as is indicated by the [cleveref package](http://ctan.org/pkg/cleveref)'s manual. Thanks @Troy.

... however! This does not change the default for all reference types. So this is not the best possible answer.