# Forcing abbreviations with cleverref

Tags: cross-referencing, cleveref

As an apposite situation of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6428), I would like to use cleveref, but it constantly prints unabbreviated text (`Chapter`, `Section`, etc.). Is there a way to force the abbreviated form (`Chap.`, `Sec.`, etc.)?

If it makes a difference, I use a KOMA-Script class:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrreprt}
```

and the full list of packages:

```
%%% PAGE DIMENSIONS
\usepackage{geometry} 
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=3.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.6cm,rmargin=2.6cm,headheight=1.3cm,headsep=1cm}
\pagestyle{headings}

%%% PACKAGES
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{paralist} 
\usepackage{verbatim} 
\usepackage{subfig} 
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb, url}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabu,longtable,booktabs,caption}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{scrpage2,datetime,tikz}
\usepackage[unicode=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[numbered]{bookmark}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
```

Comment: @ChristianHupfer and neither the referenced question has it. You don't always need a document body to explain the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know whether this is a good practise in English or not. In any case, you can use `\crefname` to provide the desired abbreviated form (by default just equations, and figures are abbreviated); I also provided non-abbreviated forms for `\Cref` since abbreviations should not be used at the beginning of a sentence:

```
\documentclass[english]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\crefname{chapter}{chap.}{chap.}
\crefname{section}{sect.}{sect.}
\Crefname{chapter}{Chapter}{Chapters}
\Crefname{section}{Section}{Sections}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test chapter}
\label{cha:test}
\section{Test section}
\label{sec:test}
As we see in \cref{sec:test} of \cref{cha:test}

\Cref{sec:test}

\Cref{cha:test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If, for some reason, you need a different variant in some part of the document, you can use something like

```
 ...{\Crefname{chapter}{Chap.}{Chap.}\Cref{cha:test}}...
```

the extra pair of braces keeps the change local.

Comment: Perhaps you should add that only few label types are `abbreviated` by default, such as `equation`, `figure` and `table`...

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I added a note; thanks. By default, `table` is not abbreviated, however.

Comment: Really? I thought it would. Thanks for correcting me! And I agree with you that constantly using abbreviations is no good style, perhaps in no language...

Comment: correct me if I got it wrong, but I cannot have duplicates of the same `\Crefname`, right? (I need it abbreviated with the capital letter in certain tables)

Comment: @Federico You're right. However, you can use `\Crefname` as many times as you want in your document, so you can say `{\Crefname{chapter}{Chap.}{Chap.}
\Cref{cha:test}}` (notice the extra anclosing braces to keep the change local) whereever you want to make a change.

Comment: Thanks! (if you don't mind I would ask you to add this to the answer)

Comment: @Federico You're welcome! No problem. I've already added a remark in my updated answer.